# Dataframe search nth largest column and store the corresponsing rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have following code to generate a pandas dataframe:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'x':[],'y':[],'w':[],'h':[]})

for idx in range(len(contours)):
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contours[idx])
    df=df.append({'x':x, 'y':y, 'w':w, 'h':h}, ignore_index=True)
```

The resulting dataframe is as follows:

```
        h      w      x      y
0    17.0  550.0   20.0  370.0
1    16.0  549.0   20.0  341.0
2     5.0    7.0  497.0  288.0
3    31.0  167.0  201.0  271.0
4    30.0   91.0   56.0  263.0
5    11.0   17.0  174.0  251.0
6     3.0    3.0   19.0  251.0
7     3.0    3.0   29.0  248.0
8    67.0  179.0  398.0  234.0
9    32.0   92.0  202.0  234.0
10   21.0   16.0  175.0  231.0
11   11.0   12.0  202.0  218.0
12   11.0    3.0    0.0  216.0
13    3.0    3.0   14.0  211.0
```

I want to get max 2 values in width (w) and return the corresponding rows:
I am able to get max 2 values using the following code:

```
a=df['w'].nlargest(2)
print(a)
```

My question is how do I store row values in a variable (in my case x=20.0, y=370.0, h=17.0 ) which correspond to the max column value

followup: I want to take w=550, and save all the values of x and y which lie in the range of w ± 5. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html) - with specifying column for looking values:

```
df = df.nlargest(2, 'w')
print (df)
      h      w     x      y
0  17.0  550.0  20.0  370.0
1  16.0  549.0  20.0  341.0
```

Comment: followup: I want to take w=550, and save all the values of x and y which lie in the range of w ± 5. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `isin` to pick rows by the pre-computed value:

```
df[df['w'].isin(a)]

      h      w     x      y
0  17.0  550.0  20.0  370.0
1  16.0  549.0  20.0  341.0
```

And to store the top value in a var, you can simply create a dictionary of the row:

```
top_dict = df[df['w'].isin(df['w'].nlargest(1))].iloc[0].to_dict()

print(top_dict)
{'h': 17.0, 'w': 550.0, 'x': 20.0, 'y': 370.0}
```

Comment: followup: I want to take w=550, and save all the values of x and y which lie in the range of w ± 5. How do I do this?

Comment: @AjinkyaBobade Can you maybe give an example of rows you want to include?

Comment: Sure,  in the above case rows 0 and 1 where (x=20,y=370 and x=20 y=341). as these  rows satisfy conditions of width(w) ± 5

Comment: @AjinkyaBobade I assume you're talking about rows where `545 < w < 555`. In that case, you need something like `df[df['w'].between(df['w'].max() - 5, df['w'].max() + 5)]` (you can replace `df['w'].max()` with `550` if that's appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, df[df['w'].between(df['w'].max() - 5, df['w'].max() + 5)] this does the work